# React Navigation : can't open keyboard with createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

With `react-navigation/native (5.9.4)` and iOS (tested on iPhone 8), I can't use `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator() (5.3.15)` and `createMaterialTopTabNavigator() (5.3.15)`.

When I use these two features the keyboard won't open (or close immediately) on iOS. This makes the inputs totally unusable.

[image]

I recreated a very simple model. With Snack Expo, On Android, everything works fine, on iOS, the keyboard does not open :

https://snack.expo.io/xUeskyMm-

In `/Navigator/BottomTabNavigator`, you can change uncomment/comment code :

```
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      {/*
      <Tab.Screen
        name="GymTopTab"
        component={GymTopTabNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Séances",
        }}
      />
      */}
      <Tab.Screen
        name="TrainingStack"
        component={TrainingStackNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Séances",
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

When I'm not using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` everything works fine. This is why I think the bug occurs when I use `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()` and `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` together. But I am very surprised that such a basic situation causes such a big problem.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution ?